# Change inner node with a variable value

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to copy an xml and replace inner text with a variable.
Here's the xslt I've created

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" exclude-result-prefixes="ns2">
 <xsl:param name="InstrumentationKey" /> 
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ns2:InstrumentationKey">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>  
        <xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$InstrumentationKey" />
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above xslt is to transform the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings"><InstrumentationKey>TestData</InstrumentationKey></ApplicationInsights>
```

I'm getting back error that <xsl:value-of not allowed in xsl:text.
Any idea how I can replace inner text with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  it should be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" exclude-result-prefixes="ns2">
 <xsl:param name="InstrumentationKey" /> 
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ns2:InstrumentationKey">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>  
        <xsl:value-of select="$InstrumentationKey" />
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```